# Sending email with groovy/ratpack

Tags: java, groovy, ratpack

I've been looking online for examples for this but I can't seem to find any. I'm trying to write a function in my groovy/ratpack web app that sends out email notification whenever an event is triggered. Any ideas would be apprecatied.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a service like SendGrid? https://sendgrid.com/pricing/

They have a free plan of 12,000 emails per month. You can use the http api with Ratpack's non blocking http client